# Asynchronous Mocha Testing with Node and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm using `beforeEach` and `afterEach` hooks to instantiate a view with a model and a user for each `it` block in the test. But in the `beforeEach` hook of the first `it` block `user.attributes` is empty. In the second one, `user.attributes` has an attribute even though it was instantiated with an empty user. Why is the second user instantiated with an attribute?

```
describe("TestView", ->
    beforeEach((done)->
        @view = new TestView({model: new SomeModel(), user: new User()})
        console.log(@view.user)
        @view.render(done)
    )

    afterEach(->
        @view?.remove()
    )

    it("should initialize and render without errors", ->
        expect(@view).to.be.ok
    )

    it("should get the test class after being clicked", (done)->
        expect($('.some-class').hasClass('test')).to.be.equal(false)
        @view.$el.click()
        setTimeout(->
            expect($('.some-class').hasClass('test')).to.be.equal(true)
            done()
        , 100) # give it 100ms to let the event handlers do their things
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` gives you an inspector for an object in the browser's Javascript Console, but the inspector is not immediately populated with all current data. By the time you can expand the user object in the console, the click has already happened.

You could get a more static snapshot to inspect by saying

```
console.log(user.clone())
```

or even

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
```

or you could just log the specific property you are interested in:

```
console.log(user.attribute)
```